# What should be the structure of a person to person store database?

Tags: php, database, database-design, mysql, laravel

I am going to create a person to person store with **Laravel**, a website where its users can **share and sell** their product or their mobile, TV, Computer, Shoes, Shirts, Books, Cars, Bags, Animal, etc.

I am going to create a table named **products** and other tables about products are, for example, **bugs, Animals, Cars, Shirts, Shoes, Computers**.

**products** table:

```
product_id   |   cat_id     |   title    |   cost    |    timestamp
```

**cars** table:

```
      id     |  product_fk  |     brand   |   model   |    type    |  Fuel  | ...
```

**computers** table:

```
     id     |  product_fk  |     brand   |   type     |    CPU     |  GPU    |  hard_disk  |  ...
```

I will create other tables with this way.

I want to search database by titles and their type , I mean I just search the **products** table

---

I want to know

1. *Is there any other way (better and easier) to do this?*
2. *What do you think about this structure?*

Comment: Hmm, there are many options to handle this. While it would not be uncommon to do it like you propose the obvious disadvantage here is the amount of tables you would need to create. Also only products with existing tables could be added. One alternative would be using a NoSQL database with a document model where you could add various types of additional information independent from product type. You would only have to define possible tags in your code. But you don't provide enough information to make a good decision, for example it would be important to know how you search this data.

Comment: I agree with thornsten muller. While it's possible to handle this with a normal relational database it's better and more "future-proof" to use a NoSQL database if you really want to do it properly.

Comment: @Alternatex can you please answer?

Comment: @Kermani Maybe someone with more experience in NoSQL can help you. Though I think your relational structure is fine if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this structure too...

```
Products:
--------
ProductID | CategoryID | Title | Cost | TimeStamp
1         | 1          | Audi  | $0   | ----- 

Specifications
--------------
SpecificationID | Specification
1               | Model
2               | Fuel
3               | HardDisk

ProductSpecifications:
----------------------
ProductSpecificationID | ProductID | SpecificationID | Value
1                      | 1         | 1               | xyz
1                      | 1         | 2               | abc
```

Comment: Thanks its a good design, But I think not working for example for fuel I have hybrid, Gas, Gasoline and other. But It gives me an Idea